# ld not picking up library

Tags: c++, ld

Inside `/usr/local/lib` I have the following files:

```
libxerces-c.so
libxerces-c.so.28
libxerces-c.so.28.0
```

My linker fails at this command:

```
g++ -m64 -o waspxs ConfigureWaspJobs.o MainWindow.o DataTypes.o waspxs.o \
    XercesString.o qrc_buttons.o moc_ConfigureWaspJobs.o moc_MainWindow.o \
    -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L../common -L../prewaspwdll -L/usr/local/lib \
    -pthread -lcommon -lprewaspwdll -lxerces-c -lQt5Widgets \
    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxerces-c
```

Note that the options include `-L/usr/local/lib` and `-lxerces-c`.

What am I missing here?

When I run `file` on the libs:

```
$ file libxerces*
libxerces-c.so:           broken symbolic link to `/home/samuel/Desktop/xerces-c-src_2_8_0/lib/libxerces-c.so.28'
libxerces-c.so.28:        symbolic link to `libxerces-c.so.28.0'
libxerces-c.so.28.0:      ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x44c1a6dbfbe5b51a17fc0ce42097af88a8e8a7f0, not stripped
libxerces-depdom.so:      broken symbolic link to `/home/samuel/Desktop/xerces-c-src_2_8_0/lib/libxerces-depdom.so.28'
libxerces-depdom.so.28:   symbolic link to `libxerces-depdom.so.28.0'
libxerces-depdom.so.28.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xc9f643c520055a931c596f713853654192a5a7fa, not stripped
```

Comment: What it says? can you post the message here?

Comment: Posting the actual linker output failure *verbatim* would likely add significant contribution to your question.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry for that. Posted the last line.

Comment: I think that "broken symbolic link to ..." is likely to be your problem. It should point at the local `libxerces-c.so.28`, not somewhere off in your (presumably) build directory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are explicitly building a 64 bit binary (as you are using `-m64`), you should make sure you have the 64 bit version of xerces installed. Usually, the 64 bit library directory would have `64` appended to it. For example: `/usr/local/lib64`.

---

The `file` command reports the symbolic link is broken. Therefore, the library cannot be found. To fix, remove the broken link, and create a fixed one.

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.so
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.so.28 /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.so
```

If your version of `ln` supports it, you can do it with a single command:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.so.28 /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.so
```

Comment: I built xerces from source so I would think that it's 64 bit.

Comment: @snowandotherjoys: Check it with `file /usr/local/lib/libxerces*` and see what that says.

Comment: I posted the output in my question. I think there's a clue there?